# how to call an image in between for a particular period in objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
       UIImageView *campFireView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
       //UIImageView *campFireView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:campFireView];

       // load all the frames of our animation
       campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Img_0.jpg"],
nil];
// all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
       campFireView.animationDuration = 1.75;
       // repeat the annimation forever
       campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 1000.0;
       // start animating
       [campFireView startAnimating];

       // add the animation view to the main window 
       [self.view addSubview:campFireView];

       [campFireView release];
```

the problem here is i want to set only one image so i have used arraywithobject but when i run this code it is giving me error that too many paramters for arrayWithObject. What is problem.Can anybody help me in solving this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrayWithObject:` takes only one parameter, so just remove the `,nil`.